# Сделать из 4-ядерного процессора 1-ядерный

Tags: windows, многопоточность, cpu

Доброе время суток, можно как то сделать из 4-ядерного процессора 1-ядерный под Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Легко. Открываете диспетчер задач и для каждой задачи ставите "set affinity" - "задать соответствие". Там выключаете все ядра, кроме одного.
А зачем вам?